# When opening any file in excel, a 1 is added to ther name, and the default is to save a new copy

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Ok...  I've searched a lot for this, but it's not an easy question to search for!

When I open any files (xls, or xlsx) in Excel 2007, excel acts like it's a read only file, essentially creating a new file with the name plus a 1 on the end...

Eg.
I open NewDoc.xlsx
Excel opens it as NewDoc1.xlsx and the save button brings up the save as dialogue in my default folder.

Does anyone know how to set it back to allowing me to open, edit and save a document without having to browse to the original document and save over it!?

Comment: [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) may be a more relevant spot to ask this question.

Comment: @slugster, thanks, I figured SO wasn't the place, but haven't come across superuser before!  Now posted -
http://superuser.com/questions/229372/when-opening-any-file-in-excel-a-1-is-added-to-ther-name-and-the-default-is-to

Answer (score 0):

Could file system permissions or file attributes be the source of the problem?

Comment: This was my immediate thought, but it's in a network folder with my user given Full Control, I also tried creating a new file in that folder, and also on my local machine just in case.  To make it even stranger, if I browse to the original file using the save as dialogue, it will let me save over the original, without any further prompts.

Comment: still, what about the attributes? what kind of a network folder exactly?